# WPF DataGrid Column Visibility Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working with a DataGrid in WPF and I'm having an issue with column visibility.  I have the ItemSource assigned to an ObservableCollection and all my bindings set up properly in XAML and everything works.  I need the ability to show and hide columns on the UI as a convenience to the user.  I've set up the bindings for column visibility in the C# file and those work fine to show and hide most columns properly.  However, DataGridTemplateColumns that contain ComboBoxes reappear as empty.  The binding is still set up properly because as soon as the data changes it's properly pushed to the UI and is visible again.  I've also verified that the underlying data is not being cleared when the column is set to be hidden.

This is what I get when I hide and then show the column with the ComboBox:[Missing ComboBox Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOHKq.png)

Full Example Code is below:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DeviceDataGrid" Margin="10,50,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model Name" IsReadOnly="true" Binding="{Binding ModelName}" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IGMP" IsReadOnly="False" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="IgmpVersion">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Margin="4" IsEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding IgmpVersionValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding IgmpVersion}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Menu Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="View" Height="25">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuViewModelName" Header="Model Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="175" IsCheckable="True" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuViewIgmp" Header="IGMP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="175" IsCheckable="True" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<ExtendedDevice> MyDevices = new ObservableCollection<ExtendedDevice>();
        GlobalVars GV = new GlobalVars();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DeviceDataGrid.ItemsSource = MyDevices;

            MyDevices.Add(new ExtendedDevice() { ModelName = "Model A", IgmpVersion = eExtendedIgmpVersion.V2 });
            MyDevices.Add(new ExtendedDevice() { ModelName = "Model B", IgmpVersion = eExtendedIgmpVersion.V3 });
            MyDevices.Add(new ExtendedDevice() { ModelName = "Model C", IgmpVersion = eExtendedIgmpVersion.Unknown });

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.DeviceDataGrid.Columns[0], DataGridColumn.VisibilityProperty, BindingHelper.CreateOneWayBindingWithConverter(GV, "ShowColumnModelName", new BooleanToVisibleConverter(), null));
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.MenuViewModelName, MenuItem.IsCheckedProperty, BindingHelper.CreateTwoWayBinding(GV, "ShowColumnModelName"));

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.DeviceDataGrid.Columns[1], DataGridColumn.VisibilityProperty, BindingHelper.CreateOneWayBindingWithConverter(GV, "ShowColumnIgmp", new BooleanToVisibleConverter(), null));
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.MenuViewIgmp, MenuItem.IsCheckedProperty, BindingHelper.CreateTwoWayBinding(GV, "ShowColumnIgmp"));
        }
    }

    public enum eExtendedIgmpVersion : int
    {
        V3 = 3,
        V2 = 2,
        Unknown = -1,
    }

    public class ExtendedDevice : DiscoveredDevice
    {
        private eExtendedIgmpVersion _IgmpVersion = eExtendedIgmpVersion.Unknown;
        public eExtendedIgmpVersion IgmpVersion
        {
            get { return _IgmpVersion; }
            set { _IgmpVersion = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public IEnumerable<eExtendedIgmpVersion> IgmpVersionValues
        {
            get
            {
                return Enum.GetValues(typeof(eExtendedIgmpVersion)).Cast<eExtendedIgmpVersion>();
            }
        }

        public ExtendedDevice() : base() { }
    }

    public class DiscoveredDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _ModelName;
        public string ModelName
        {
            get { return _ModelName; }
            set { _ModelName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        public DiscoveredDevice()
        {
        }
    }

    static class BindingHelper
    {
        public static Binding CreateTwoWayBinding(Object Source, String Path)
        {
            Binding myBinding = new Binding();
            myBinding.Source = Source;
            myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(Path);
            myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

            return myBinding;
        } 

        public static Binding CreateOneWayBindingWithConverter(Object Source, String Path, IValueConverter Converter, Object ConverterParameter)
        {
            Binding myBinding = new Binding();
            myBinding.Source = Source;
            myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(Path);
            myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            myBinding.Converter = Converter;
            myBinding.ConverterParameter = ConverterParameter;

            return myBinding;
        }
    }

    public class GlobalVars : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        

        private bool _ShowColumnModelName = true;
        public bool ShowColumnModelName
        {
            get { return _ShowColumnModelName; }
            set { _ShowColumnModelName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }        

        private bool _ShowColumnIgmp = true;
        public bool ShowColumnIgmp
        {
            get { return _ShowColumnIgmp; }
            set { _ShowColumnIgmp = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }        

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    public class BooleanToVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool? input = value as bool?;
            return input == true ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you throw together a minimal example that allows us to test what you're seeing? Chances are, you'll find the solution in the course of doing so.

Comment: Why your ConvertBack method throws exception?

Comment: @AliM When you right click on `IValueConverter` in the class definition and choose "Implement Interface" from the popup menu, it creates stubs that throw that exception. `ConvertBack()` is never called in this case, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @EdPlunkett  I've edited to provide a complete example.

Comment: Lovely MVCE, thank you! Unfortunately it works perfectly for me and hides both columns when asked.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The columns hide properly, but when they're shown again the ComboBox object is missing the data.  I've attached an image link in the OP above the XAML.  (I don't have the rep to post inline.)

Comment: One suggestion I'd make to simplify matters: Put `<local:GlobalVars x:Key="GV"/>` in Window.Resources (or `App.xaml` resources), and `GV = FindResource("GV") as GlobalVars;` in the MainWindow constructor. Then you can bind to it in the XAML with `Source={StaticResource GV}`.

Comment: @Chris Ohhhh derp quite right thanks, let me take another look

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. I put a DataContextChanged handler on the combobox. When I unhide the column, that event is raised. In the handler, `var cb = (sender as DataContext)`. cb.DataContext is as it should be. cb.ItemsSource and SelectedItem are null. `cb.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget()` doesn't change anything. I can't get those bindings to update. The getters on the viewmodel are not called. If I bind labels to those properties in the DataTemplate, the getters are called by those bindings and they show what they should.

Comment: Bizarrely, if I create two labels in the cell template bound to those two properties, give the labels names, and bind the ComboBox's properties to their respective Content properties (`ItemsSource="{Binding Content, ElementName=values}"`  etc.), that restores the ComboBox on column un-hide. That's useless of course, being one-way. But it illustrates something. I only wish I knew what.

Comment: Have you tried a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`? They're a horrorshow to get working, but worth a try in this case.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I haven't tried `DataGridComboBoxColumn` because I wanted to show other things in the column with the ComboBox.  In one particular instance I have a checkbox next to it for a related property.  I tried modifying to use the `Window.Resources` method you mentioned and it had no effect.  I also tried hooking up to the `IsVisibleChanged` event handler and noticed that it fires only when i hide the column, not when it's shown again.  I tried binding the ComboBox's visibility directly to the GV property and it still only fired when hidden, not shown.

Comment: I've got some progress made by specifying `Mode=OneWay` binding on the ComboBox, which is fine for my application.  I wonder if the issue is that I'm using enums and it's trying to compare the `SelectedItem` to the `ItemsSource` by reference and deeming it to be invalid.  Now I don't exactly know how I would go about fixing that problem, but it's a start.

Comment: @Chris Enums are value types. Comparison will be by value.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That’s what I thought too.  I hooked to the `DropDownOpened` event handler so I could watch the objects better and noticed that everything was fine before hiding and after hiding it was all null.  The thing I thought was odd was the the `IsVisibleChanged` still only fired on hide, not show.